# What is wrong with this PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, meta-tags, keyword

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];
if($url == "") {
  die("Invalid Request! Missing Parameter 1!");
  exit;
}
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);
$key = $tags['keywords'];
$desc = $tags['description'];

$con = mysql_connect('HOST', 'USER', 'PASS') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('zach_WebLock', $con) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT INTO `Keyword` (`Site`, `Keyword`, `Description`) VALUES ('".$site."', '".$key."', '".$desc."')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo '<b>Site: <u>'.$url.'</u></b>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<b>Description:</b>';
echo '<br>';
echo $desc;
echo '<br><br>';

$keys = explode(',', $key);
foreach($keys as $word) {
  echo $word;
  echo '<br>';
} 



?>
```

This script extracts the keywords and description for the URL in the ?url= variable. It displays all the information, doesn't raise any errors but doesn't write the information to the DB. Any ideas? (

(I have left out the mysql_real_escape_string() for testing)

Comment: Have you checked the db to see if there are any records being inserted (to check there's no blank fields being written)?

Comment: I notice that you have a fieldname equal to the Tablename and both are have `` around then. Maybe mysql is confused and thinks they refer to the same? Perhaps you could rename the field to exclude this? Keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to insert the variable `$site` which is not defined. Perhaps you meant `$url`?

If that's not the case, please provide more information. Do you get any output from `mysql_error()`?

Comment: Thanks! I have read that script several times and didn't catch it! It says I can't accept this answer for another 10 mins... but yours is the one I'll accept! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add '' to allow for the AUTO INCREMENTATION for your primary key in the KeyWord table, which should stop the MySQL Error from occuring.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 'Keyword' VALUES ('','$site', '$key', '$desc')";
echo $query;
```

If that doesn't  fix your solution, I'd recommend echoing out the query when you run the script and look any blank values, fix where necessary. If you're still having issues copy paste the your expected INSERT Query that was echoed from the script and test it in PhpMyAdmin and see if you get a different result (errors).